# data set size limitation with lm in R

Tags: r

I have been banging my head against an issue with lm in R and thought I would share my findings and ask people's opinion about it.

I was fitting a linear model on some data that clearly showed a very strong linear relation. However I was suprised to get poor results (r2 ~ 0.46). My data has just over 6000 rows.
Then I ran the same code but on a sample of the data and I got the results I was expecting (r2 ~ 0.99).
So I thought, OK, there may a weird point in there messing up with everything (although there was nothing obvious when I ran the classic data quality checks). I tried hard to find that point to no avail. But then I realised: this is not due to a given point, but to the size of the data set.

In my case (I'm working on an Azure compute instance, 16G RAM) the limit is at n=4096.

I created the test piece of code below and it reveals the issue (again: on my machine). Yes it is a very silly example but that's not the question ;)

```
# set some coefficient values 
some.noise <- 100
coef_ <- 3.8
interc_ <- -1.2

# set sample size (no. of rows)
n.sample <- 4096

# very basic linear relation with some noise
feature <- runif(n = n.sample, min = 0, max = 200)
outcome <- (coef_*feature + interc_) + runif(n=n.sample, max=some.noise)

df_ <- tibble(feat = feature, tar = outcome)
ggplot(df_) + geom_point(aes(x=feat, y=tar))

lm_ <- lm(tar ~ feat, data=df_)
summary(lm_)
# Coefficients:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept) 23.662659   1.429095   16.56   <2e-16 ***
#   feat         4.167374   0.006125  680.44   <2e-16 ***
#   ---
# 
# Multiple R-squared:  0.966,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.966 

# now the same as above, with just one more row
n.sample <- 4097
feature <- runif(n = n.sample, min = 0, max = 200)
outcome <- (coef_*feature + interc_) + runif(n=n.sample, max=some.noise)

df_ <- tibble(feat = feature, tar = outcome)
ggplot(df_) + geom_point(aes(x=feat, y=tar))

lm_ <- lm(tar ~ feat, data=df_)
summary(lm_)
# Coefficients:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept) -825.0953    42.1167  -19.59   <2e-16 ***
#   feat           8.3911     0.1822   46.05   <2e-16 ***
# 
# Multiple R-squared:  0.467,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.4669
```

So here are my questions:

- anyone knows what is going on? Is this related to the issue of lm switching from QR to LU decomposition? If so, I find strange that the results are so much different
- more importantly, is there a way to know? I mean, I could never have found out had it not be such an obvious case (of underlying linear relation). Now I wonder how many times in the past I have concluded that the fit was really poor when actually it was a numeric issue...

I'd be very interested in having some expert's opinion on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I cannot replicate your result. When I run the provided code the results are nearly identical. What is the `sessionInfo()` in the R session where you are experiencing the issue?

Comment: cannot replicate the issue either. tried several sample sizes. additionally to posting sessionInfo, could you use the [reprex-package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/)?

Comment: Maybe you could also expand what you mean by "lm switching from QR to LU decomposition" as far as I can see from the documentation `stats::lm()`, for argument `method`, "currently, only `method = "qr"` is supported."

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. Indeed I have had further odd issues popping up so I got suspicious. I tried the same thing (code posted above) runnin R and Rstudio on my personal machine and it did not reproduce the problem. So this is not actually a problem with R per se or with `lm` but there must be something going wrong between R / RStudio and Azure. So more of an "R on Azure" related problem. Thank you again.